# Z-index with stacking context

Tags: html, css, angular

I have html tree in shortcut

```
<body>
  <document-list></document-list>
  <div>
    <document-image></document-image> => parentStaticContext: html z-index:20
    <document-form> => parentStaticContext: html z-index:30
        <input></input> => parentStaticContext: html z-index:1
    </document-form>
  </diV>
</body>
```

Document-image is on the left side of page, document-form on the right. And I want display some part of input over Document-image. But now z-index not working. I set for this elements position absolute or relative.

Comment: could you create a plunker for it ?

Comment: [Do you know about `stacking context`?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `div` tag as `position: relative`.
 use `position:  absolute` on input tag. 
 use `margin-left` to align it accordingly.

```
<body>
  <document-list [style.position]="'relative'"></document-list>
  <div>
    <document-image></document-image> => parentStaticContext: html z-index:20
    <document-form > => parentStaticContext: html z-index:30
        <input [style.position]="'absolute'" class="margin-left-30px"></input> => parentStaticContext: html z-index:1
    </document-form>
  </div>
</body>
```

hope it helps!